# Kivy Blender Animation

Tags: blender, kivy

I've got a blended ocean that I want to animate in a Kivy program. Are there other methods of producing the animation aside from getting a bunch of frames and then making a sequential image out of the frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to just create an image animation sequence - either a series of PNGs or an animated GIF - and if the sequence is static, this is generally the best option anyway. However, you could look at tshirtman's [ddd](https://github.com/TangibleDisplay/garden-ddd) garden module, which handles 3d rendering in Kivy, and see if it does what you need.

Comment: That's about what I figured. Thanks for confirming.